# export env at archlinux shell

Tags: linux, shell, archlinux

when I at company , I have to export 3 enviroment variables, http_proxy,https_proxy,all_proxy,

I wrote a file ~/bin/setproxy like this

```
#! /bin/sh
export http_proxy=http://......:8888
export https_proxy=http://......:8888
export all_proxy=http://......:8888
```

but when I execute this file at bash, then use env | grep http_proxy , I got nothing.
but "source ~/bin/setproxy" works, but is there any way short this to 1 word command.
I wrote another file only 1 line,

```
source ~/bin/setproxy
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

When you execute that script a sub-shell is spawned and the three export are perfomed in that shell, when the script finishes, the sub-shell exits, that's why you don't see the environment variables as set.

You could put that code in a function, say in your `.bashrc`, and call that, this way it will work, something like the following:

```
function setproxy {
    export http_proxy=http://......:8888
    export https_proxy=http://......:8888
    export all_proxy=http://......:8888
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is because you are executing either:

```
~/bin/setproxy
```

or:

```
your_other_file_which_sources_setproxy
```

In *both* those cases, they run in a subshell which means the export is in that subshell, *not* the shell you're calling them from.

You can either use the short form of `source`:

```
. ~/bin/setproxy
```

or create an alias:

```
alias sp='source ~/bin/setproxy'
```

in your `.bashrc` or other startup scripts.

That latter solution will allow you to just execute:

```
sp
```

to do the work.